What does it mean by `-fno-signed-char, --signed-char` for gcc & clang?
In clang's documentation, I find a strange option:
-fno-signed-char, --signed-char
I know -fno-signed-char is equivalent to -funsigned-char, I just wonder:
1. What does it mean by following --signed-char?
2. Is --signed-char equivalent to -fsigned-char ?

--signed-char and --unsigned-char are historical options. -f... are relatively new and made for consistency with other -f.... They are equivalent.

Behavior
The documentation
says:

-fsigned-char, -fno-signed-char, --signed-char
char is signed

This somewhat cryptic notation means that -fsigned-char and
--signed-char both cause char to be a signed type, and
-fno-signed-char causes char to be an unsigned type.
(Part of the reason the documentation is so cryptic is that it is
automatically generated from the internal implementation shown below.
That's not an excuse, just an explanation.)
Later, the documentation says:

-funsigned-char, -fno-unsigned-char, --unsigned-char

without any further description.  The intent is for the user to infer
the meaning from the option names and from the behavior of the similarly
named options above.  Specifically, -funsigned-char and
--unsigned-char cause char to be unsigned, and -fno-unsigned-char
causes char to be signed.
Demonstration
Test program test.c:
// test.c
// Is `char` signed?

#include <stdio.h>                     // printf

int main(void)
{
  char c = (char)128;
  printf("c is %d, so char is %s\n",
         (int)c,
         (c > 0? "unsigned" : "signed"));
  return 0;
}

// EOF

Compiling and running with all six options on Linux/x86_64 using
Clang-16.0.0:
$ clang -Wall -fsigned-char test.c && ./a.out
c is -128, so char is signed
$ clang -Wall -fno-signed-char test.c && ./a.out
c is 128, so char is unsigned
$ clang -Wall --signed-char test.c && ./a.out
c is -128, so char is signed
$ clang -Wall -funsigned-char test.c && ./a.out
c is 128, so char is unsigned
$ clang -Wall -fno-unsigned-char test.c && ./a.out
c is -128, so char is signed
$ clang -Wall --unsigned-char test.c && ./a.out
c is 128, so char is unsigned

Internal definition
The clang driver program options are defined in
clang/include/clang/Driver/Options.td.
As one example, the --signed-char option is defined on
line 5669
of version 18.1.8 as an alias for -fsigned-char:
def _signed_char : Flag<["--"], "signed-char">, Alias<fsigned_char>;

In Clang, the driver options --signed-char,
--unsigned-char, -fsigned-char, and -funsigned-char were all added
together on 2009-06-05 in
commit 327f0b55936a6.
The driver program interprets these options and maps them to the
-fno-signed-char option of clang -cc1 (the compiler front-end proper)
starting at
line 3959 of clang/lib/Driver/ToolChains/Clang.cpp:
  // -fsigned-char is default.
  if (const Arg *A = Args.getLastArg(options::OPT_fsigned_char,
                                     options::OPT_fno_signed_char,
                                     options::OPT_funsigned_char,
                                     options::OPT_fno_unsigned_char)) {
    if (A->getOption().matches(options::OPT_funsigned_char) ||
        A->getOption().matches(options::OPT_fno_signed_char)) {
      CmdArgs.push_back("-fno-signed-char");
    }
  } else if (!isSignedCharDefault(T)) {
    CmdArgs.push_back("-fno-signed-char");
  }

The clang -cc1 option -fno-signed-char (the only variant it
recognizes) is also defined in Options.td:
defm signed_char : BoolFOption<"signed-char",
  LangOpts<"CharIsSigned">, DefaultTrue,
         // ^^^^^^^^^^^^
         //  effect is to control this language option
  NegFlag<SetFalse, [], [ClangOption, CC1Option], "char is unsigned">,
                                   // ^^^^^^^^^
                                   // recognized by clang -cc1
  PosFlag<SetTrue, [], [ClangOption], "char is signed">>,
  ShouldParseIf<!strconcat("!", open_cl.KeyPath)>;

Since you linked to the documentation of Clang, I assume that's the
implementation of interest, so I didn't dig into implementation or
history for GCC.  But Clang generally follows conventions that GCC
established, so if you're interested in the pre-2009 history, that is
where the trail goes next.

The Clang documentation you link to lists all forms of a switch, both the forms that turn the option on and the forms that turn it off, and leave it to you to figure out that the “no-” form turns it off.
In contrast, the GCC documentation explicitly says “… the negative form of -ffoo is -fno-foo. This manual documents only one of these two forms, whichever one is not the default.”
Using both a positive form and a negative form is a contradiction. Testing shows that GCC and Clang appear to use the last one listed.
